# Reduction trees in LK

Tags: logic

In propositional calculus there is a possibility to check whether a given formula is deducible from a given system of formulas, or not, by constructing the [tree of sequents](https://www.nayuki.io/page/propositional-sequent-calculus-prover) that clarifies everything. In predicate calculus this is impossible in general case, because when we build this tree the choice of branches becomes ambiguous. However, often the construction of such a tree [is easy even for the sequents with quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Example_derivations). I am not a specialist in this field, and the examples that come to my mind are all simple, i.e. this tree appears immediately. Can anybody give me a "more or less difficult sequent with quantifiers", for which the construction of such a tree is not obvious? I would appreciate an example in a simple language, preferably, in the language of set theory.

Answer (score 1):

I can't write down a concrete example in full (alas, this margin is too small), but you could take a sequent where

- the left-hand side contains all the (finitely many) axioms of NBG set theory, and
- the right-hand side is some open conjecture (e.g. the Riemann Hypothesis) written down in the language of set theory.

Figuring out whether the sequent has a proof tree is then the same as figuring out whether or not the Riemann Hypothesis is a theorem of NBG -- which is well known to be the case if and only if it is a theorem of ZFC.

If you manage that, you will be famous!

---

For something simpler than all of set theory you can also code up an instance of [Post's correspondence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem) as a theory with a number of axioms of the form
$$ \forall x,y\Bigl( x\sim y \to f_1(f_2(\cdots(f_n(x))\cdots)) \sim f'_1(f'_2(\cdots(f'_m(y))\cdots)) \Bigr)$$
and ask whether those axioms together with $0\sim 0$ entail $\exists z ( z\ne 0\land z\sim z)$.

Comment: Is there an example that illustrates the difficulties? I need an illustration for students.

Comment: :) Is everything so hopeless?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: It's not really clear to me which kind of answer you're expecting. The PCP is one of the simplest "known to be difficult" problems I can think of right away. Would the word problem for groups seem more accessible to you?

Comment: Is there is a sequent (more or less short, and in set theory) such that when we build this tree this ambiguity appears so that it becomes not clear what to do? Not a great problem, just an exercise for students.

Comment: I'll edit the question.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: It's still unclear why the PCP example in the second half of the problem doesn't do what you want. The $0\sim 0$ assumption is atomic and doesn't help with anything, and everything else on the left is universally quantified, and the goal on the left is existentially quantified. So the last rule in a cut-free proof _must_ be either $\forall L$ or $\exists R$, both of which require us to pull a term out of the air -- and there's nothing to tell us which term would be a good choice!

Comment: This requires an explanation of a new language...

Answer (score 1):

Formal proofs get large very quickly for even some simple theorems in elementary arithmetic when starting with elementary axioms. So, you could put the Peano axioms in the left hand side, and some fairly elementary result about arithmetic in the right hand site (you may have to include some relevant instance of the induction schema on the left hand side!), and most likely that will already not be a trivial tree.

Oh!  How about this one for sets ... (you said you wanted sets anyway ...):

$\forall x \forall y (x \subseteq y \leftrightarrow \forall z (z \in x \rightarrow z \in y))$

$\forall y \forall x (x \in pow(y) \leftrightarrow x \subseteq y)$

$\therefore \forall y \forall z (y \subseteq z \leftrightarrow pow(y) \subseteq pow(z))$

As a sequent:

$\forall x \forall y (x \subseteq y \leftrightarrow \forall z (z \in x \rightarrow z \in y)) , \forall y \forall x (x \in pow(y) \leftrightarrow x \subseteq y) \vdash \forall y \forall z (y \subseteq z \leftrightarrow pow(y) \subseteq pow(z))$

Fairly easy proof .. but I bet that tree would be fairly large nevertheless ...

Comment: Hm... How will I put the axiom of induction into this sequent? I thought there is a more or less simple example, without those horrors.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Yes, I've been trying to find something suitable that's not too hard nor too easy; just hard enough to get your point across to the students ... please give me some more time ...

Comment: Of course! This is not urgent.

Comment: If possible, please, use the language of set theory. I am starting the course with it, it is desirable to give them the necessary examples at this step.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I just gave an example involving sets ... it's not using the ZFC axioms, but I just gave a simple definition of subset and power set.

Comment: Does this mean that I must put all the ZFC axioms into this sequent? Either they will shoot me on seeing this, or, more likely, I will drown myself when thinking about this.

Comment: Or I did not understand... What is the sequent?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Hmm, both seem bad options (proof by cases!).  But no, you can derive the theorem from the two definitions alone; no further axioms are needed.  In fact, you could start with an even simpler one, where you have to prove $\forall x x \in pow(x)$ from those two axioms .. that tree will probably be fairly simple ... and then you could do this one ... where the tree will be a good it more complicated (I think)

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I just put it as a sequent

Comment: I would say, this is so bulky that it's impossible to see the real problem behind these bunchings... The student will say that perhaps the problem is just the volume of work, not the qualitative obstacles (in comparison with the situation in propositional calculus).